# http://bi/ It works! What kind of domain name is this?

Tags: dns, domain-name

I just mistyped a URL and the browser displayed a page saying "It works!"

How does DNS resolve these names? What are they?

```
~> curl http://bi/
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>


~> nslookup bi

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   bi
Address: 196.2.8.205
```

Comment: Is this question about DNS in general, or a specific library resolver? If it is the former, it's probably not a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not normally done, but it looks like the bi NIC entered a domain record for the TLD itself. When you do a PTR (Reverse DNS) record search on that IP you get the following:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
205.8.2.196.in-addr.arpa    name = ns.nic.bi.
```

Normally TLD (Top-level domains) should now have A records attached to them.

The DNS records for bi are as follows:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bi.                IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bi.         38400   IN  TXT "Check the website http://www.nic.bi"
bi.         38400   IN  TXT "Top-level Domain of the Republic of Burundi"
bi.         38400   IN  TXT "NIC Burundi"
bi.         38400   IN  TXT "Top-level Domain of .bi"
bi.         38400   IN  A   196.2.8.205
bi.         38400   IN  SOA ns.nic.bi. registrar.nic.bi. 2011070201 21600 3600
```

Comment: Please don't link to scraper sites. Original on Serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/154991/why-do-some-tld-have-an-mx-record-on-the-zone-root-e-g-ai

Comment: @ Thilo Sorry, didn't know. Thanks for the original link.

Answer (score 3):

A domain name is made up of one or more parts separated by dots. The name `bi` has only one part, and therefore does not need any dots.

Domain names *may* have an A (Address) record associated with them. It looks like `bi` does, but for example `uk` does not.

Answer (score 2):

It's the top level code for Burundi. It is the same site as www.bi.

Comment: It's not *necessarily* the same as `www.bi`, and could refer to a completely different site.

Comment: True, but in this case it is the same data. Or was, in the Google cache.

Comment: Are they supposed to do this? `http://de/` does not work, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Once upon a time, in an arpanet far away, Mockapetris wrote the initial specification for DNS. As written, absolute names ended with `.`, and relative names did not.

Well, that idea lasted about 25 seconds in the face of actual human beings typing in names. Instead, unqualified names are relative -- unless they happen to be tlds. In which case they aren't.